# Use dplyr to compute lagging difference

Tags: r, dplyr

My data frame consists of three columns: state name, year, and the tax receipt for each year and each state. Below is an example for just one state.

```
  year RealTaxRevs
1 1971     8335046
2 1972     9624026
3 1973    10498935
4 1974    10052305
5 1975     8708381
6 1976     8911262
7 1977    10759032
```

I'd like to compute the change in tax receipt from one year to the next, for each  state. I used the following code:

```
data %>% group_by(state) %>% summarise(diff(RealTaxRevs, lag = 1, differences = 1))
```

but it gives me "Error: expecting a single value".

Could anyone explain this error message, and help me do this correctly using dplyr? Thank you.

Comment: It looks like you need `mutate` rather than `summarise`. Also, you'll need to add an `NA` as the first value, since `diff` returns a vector of length n-1 when given a vector of length n. So the code would be: `mutate(c(NA, diff(RealTaxRevs)))`. You don't need to specify `lag` or `differences`, as they default to 1.

Comment: @eipi10 That works perfectly. Thank you :).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `diff` like function, then consider using the `zoo` library as well. Then you can have code which looks like the following:

```
library(zoo)
diff(as.zoo(1:4), na.pad=T)
```

In a data frame setting it would be like:

```
dat <- data.frame(a=c(8335046, 9624026, 10498935, 10052305, 8708381, 8911262, 10759032))
dat %>% mutate(b=diff(as.zoo(a), na.pad=T))
#          a        b
# 1  8335046       NA
# 2  9624026  1288980
# 3 10498935   874909
# 4 10052305  -446630
# 5  8708381 -1343924
# 6  8911262   202881
# 7 10759032  1847770
```

This way you can easily increase the number of lags, without continually adding `NA`

```
dat %>% mutate(b2=diff(as.zoo(a), lag=2, na.pad=T))
#          a       b2
# 1  8335046       NA
# 2  9624026       NA
# 3 10498935  2163889
# 4       NA       NA
# 5  8708381 -1790554
# 6  8911262       NA
# 7 10759032  2050651
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use `data.table`

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(data)[, Diffs := RealTaxRevs - shift(RealTaxRevs)[[1]], state]
```